# Wait for function to execute Ajax call before starting 2nd function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that is called by a click event. After this function is closed, the page gets partly updated with an ajax call of that function (the ajax call is executed if a condition is 'wrong').
I want another function to be executed and check how many items were being loaded with the ajax call after all the page refreshing is done. I thought of document.ready for the 2nd function, but I don't know how to start that 2nd function. Any help would be very much appreciated!

```js
$(function() {
  $('.button').click(function(){
    if ('a' === 'b'){
      alert('right');
    } else {
      alert('wrong');
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  function function2() {
  alert('function2');
}
});
```

```css
.button{
  display: inline;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">button</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to implement the check of how many items (.loopload) were loaded in the ajax call, but it always shows the number of items before the ajax refresh. I get the alert with the old number of items, I click ok, then the div of the ajax call gets refreshed.

```
var wait = $ajaxinateLoop.load(str +  ' #AjaxinateLoop');
  $.when(wait).done(function (){
    alert($('.loopload').length);
  });
```

Comment: "after all the page refreshing is done" so after the ajax call?

Comment: @Will Yes, the Ajax call is made the first function, but it seems the page update is done only after the function is closed.

Comment: A partial page "refresh" doesn't trigger `$(document).ready`. You could call the second function in your AJAX handler.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you for your answer! I edited my question and updated it. I already tried to implement it within the ajax call of the function, but the ajax update is done afterwards, I don't know why...

Comment: You know AJAX stands for "_Asynchronous Javascript And Xml_"? An AJAX call is asynchronous, the results are not existing before the call has been completed.

Comment: As said in a previous comment, "_call the second function in your AJAX handler_", i.e. in the code which actually receives the results from the server.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you! This gave me a good hint! I now found $( document ).ajaxStop(function() {  I can just put this function seperately, as I only use this one ajax call in my project

Comment: AjaxStart and ajaxStop are handler for any call on the page. So that function will be triggered by any Ajax call on the page, not only one specific. What’s wrong with appending the code you want to the code that refreshes the page? Why do you need another function when you just do the calculations after the dom have been refreshed?

Comment: @LelioFaieta I'm just very bad in programming and don't know how I could manage that. If I put the code as in my post with '$.when(wait).done(function (){...' in the line below the code, the function is executed before the ajax call is complete. As Teemu mentioned because of ajax is asynchronous. I just put the ajaxStop function in the line after the ajax call, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

With the help here, I implemented the check of the loaded products of the ajax call in the success answer of the call itself.
Thank you all for your help!!!
The function is executed after the Ajax call is complete and shows the correct number.

```
$ajaxinateLoop.load(str +  ' #AjaxinateLoop', function() {
  alert($('.loopload').length);
});
```

Comment: As mentioned by Leilo Faieta, this will be called by any ajax call, so not necessarily the one you want. Why don't you put this count in `complete: function() {...}` of your ajax call itself, which will be called when your call has finished, after `success` or `error`?

Comment: @Will Thank you so much!! Now finally I understood and updated my previous answer.